# How to read string, char , int all from one file untill find eof in c++?

Tags: c++, file, eof

What's wrong with my code? I want to get intput from file (first one string, then a char , then int). I want it for whole file. Here is my code. This is giving me so pain. What can i do? Please help me.

```
//file handling
//input from text file
//xplosive


#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
ifstream infile ("indata.txt");

int main()
{
    const int l=50;
    //string t_ques;
    char t_ques[l];
    char t_ans;
    int t_time_limit;


    while(!infile.eof())
    //while(infile)
    {
        infile.getline(t_ques,l);
        //infile >> t_ans ;
        infile.get(t_ans);
        infile >> t_time_limit;

        cout << t_ques << endl;
        cout << t_ans << endl;
        cout << t_time_limit << endl;
    }




    return 0;
}
```

my indata.txt file contain

```
what is my name q1?
t
5
what is my name q2?
f
3
what is my name q3?
t
4
what is my name q4?
f
8

out put should be the same.
but my while loop don't terminate.
```

Comment: What input do you provide?  What output do you get?

Comment: could give some sample input, that is a sample content of input file.

Comment: what is my name q1?
t
5
what is my name q2?
f
3
what is my name q3?
t
4
what is my name q4?
f
8

Comment: @Xplosive It'd be easier to understand the file content plus output you receive if you edit your question rather than posting them as a comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A number of things:

- eof checking isn't appropriate (most of the time). Instead, check stream state
- don't use `read` as it won't skip whitespace
- after your timelimit,  ignore input until the end of the line

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream infile ("indata.txt");
    std::string t_ques;
    char t_ans;
    int t_time_limit;

    std::getline(infile, t_ques);
    while (infile >> t_ans >> t_time_limit)
    {
        cout << t_ques << endl;
        cout << t_ans << endl;
        cout << t_time_limit << endl;

        infile.ignore();
        std::getline(infile, t_ques);
    }
}
```

See it **[live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=62d53a6893778b2c55c5324a844415a2-41c3b518d881d074a72e5a206a8ae495)**

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this expression:

```
infile.open("indata.txt", ios::in);
// ...same loop...
infile >> t_ques >> t_ans >> t_time_limit;

// At the end close the file
infile.close();
```

Comment: won't parse the whole question